# Make a link active from the base.html.twig on Navbar in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I researched a lot of things on stack and any other sources.
I found some interesting ideas but couldn't apply them as i'm a student and cannot just yet know where to put things directly in their right spot.

So I got this code right in the base.html.twig

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="{{ path('book_index') }}">Accueil<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="{{ path('book_ourBooks') }}">Nos livres</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ path('book_aboutUs') }}">Être édité</a></li>
                </ul>
```

and I would like, without using Jquery, being able to show the active when I click on a Link and going to that page.

I found that sort of code :

```
class="{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == '_list' %}active{% endif %}"
```

(and other things looking nearly similar)
But I really don't know how and where to put it with my own link and such.
If any help is given, this would be really appreciated, thank you :)

ps: i'm using symfony 2.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to insert the code on your `li's` like this:

```
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == '_RouteName' %}active{% endif %}">
                    <a href="{{ path('book_index') }}">Accueil<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == '_RouteName' %}active{% endif %}">
                 <a href="{{ path('book_ourBooks') }}">Nos livres</a>
                </li>
                <li class="{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == '_RouteName' %}active{% endif %}">
                <a href="{{ path('book_aboutUs') }}">Être édité</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Replace `_RouteName` with the correct `_route` for each link.

Comment: Done! I can't give you a +1 I don't know why, but i validated it :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered but I found a neat approach for a different situation which might help somebody who has submenus, just like me:

You can search for a substring inside string in twig

```
{# returns true #}

{{ 'ca' in 'car' }}
```

What I did with my routes and navigation to make the links active

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ url('admin_agency_index') }}"
       class="{% if 'admin_agency_' in app.request.attributes.get('_route') %}active{% endif %}">
        <i class="lnr lnr-apartment"></i>
          <span>Agencies</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

My agency routes are named like:

- admin_agency_new
- admin_agency_edit
- admin_agency_delete

In that case, if you reach a submenu for adding an agency for example, you will still have active class in your html.